# Django Class Based Views - Arbitrary Date Range?

Tags: django, django-class-based-views

In my Django project I want to display a list of some model (hypothetically, let's use blog posts) and by default, show the list of posts from this month. However, I would also like to be able to show all the posts between an arbitrary date range.

I was looking at the [MonthArchiveView](http://ccbv.co.uk/projects/Django/1.7/django.views.generic.dates/MonthArchiveView/) which perfectly meets my first want, but I don't think it would for my second.

I was also looking at [ArchiveIndexView](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/class-based-views/generic-date-based/#archiveindexview) (which seems similar to ListView?) but I'm not sure if that easily does what I want, either.

Does anyone have any recommendations? Are the built in generic views capable of doing what I'm looking for, or should I go ahead and write my own?

Thanks!

Comment: i love django views, but not class-based ones.

Comment: The date views are designed to chunk by fixed time periods and support navigation links like 'last month' - I'd probably use a `ListView` to do this, if I used the class based generic views at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the answer here is to create a custom CBV. I've gone ahead and done so, an child of ListView with some inspiration from the DateMixin and BaseDateListView classes. Code will be maintained [here](https://gist.github.com/JDougherty/7b054acba00d1079dc89) but for posterity is included below:

```
class ArbitraryDateListView(ListView):
    date_field = None
    date_format = '%Y-%m-%d'
    since_date = None
    until_date = None
    auto_until_date = False

    def get_date_field(self):
        if self.date_field is None:
            raise ImproperlyConfigured("%s.date_field is required." % self.__class__.__name__)
        return self.date_field

    def get_date_format(self):
        """
        Get a date format string in strptime syntax to be used to parse the date from url variables.
        """
        return self.date_format

    def get_since_date(self):
        """
        Return the start date for which this view should display data
        """
        since_date = self.since_date
        if since_date is None:
            try:
                since_date = self.kwargs['since']
            except KeyError:
                try:
                    since_date = self.request.GET['since']
                except KeyError:
                    raise Http404("No since date specified")
        format = self.get_date_format()
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(since_date, format).date()

    def get_until_date(self):
        """
        Return the end date for which this view should display data
        """
        until_date = self.until_date
        if until_date is None:
            try:
                until_date = self.kwargs['until']
            except KeyError:
                try:
                    until_date = self.request.GET['until']
                except KeyError:
                    if self.auto_until_date:
                        return self.get_until_date_from_since_date()
                    else:
                        raise Http404("No until date specified")
        format = self.get_date_format()
        return datetime.datetime.strptime(until_date, format).date()

    def get_until_date_from_since_date(self):
        """
        Return a calculated end date from start date when end date is not provided
        """
        if self.auto_until_date:
            raise NotImplementedError("If auto_util_date=True, get_until_date_from_since_date must be implemented")

    def get_queryset(self):
        queryset = super(ArbitraryDateListView, self).get_queryset()
        date_field = self.get_date_field()
        since = self.get_since_date()
        until = self.get_until_date()
        lookup_kwargs = {
            '%s__gte' % date_field: since,
            '%s__lt' % date_field: until,
        }
        queryset = queryset.filter(**lookup_kwargs).order_by('-%s' % date_field)
        return queryset

    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = {'since': self.get_since_date(),
                   'until': self.get_until_date()}
        context.update(kwargs)
        return super(ArbitraryDateListView, self).get_context_data(**context)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a class that extends from ListView and set the context overriding the parent method for that. Inside that method you can call a function that filters the objects you need.
You can see the example in the [documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-display/#adding-extra-context).

Also, to get objects with a date in some data range i do something like this:

```
def get_objects_in_some_range(self):
        now = datetime.now()
        current = self.filter(end_date__gte=now)
        current = current.filter(start_date__lte=now)
        return current
```

You could pass it some arguments to make filter the dates you want.